# How to prove all zeros of this polynomial satisfy $|z|<M+1$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

The problem is as follows:

$P(z) = z^n + a_1z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n$ satisfies $|P(z)|\leq M$ when $|z|\leq 1$, prove:

1)If $R > 1$, then $|P(z)|\leq M R^n$ when $|z|\leq R$.

2)All zeros of $P(z)$ lie in $|z|<1+M$.

I have proved 1), and didn't figure out how it may be used to prove 2)...

I think on $|z|=1+M$ we might have $|P(z)-z|<|z^n|$, if so, Rouche's theorem will do the work. But I can't prove the inequality. I also tried induction on n, that didn't work either.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: [Not exact but a similar upper bound for zeros](https://captainblack.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/cauchys-upper-bound-for-the-roots-of-a-polynomial/) given by Cauchy

Comment: I'm interested also in the first question

Comment: @Pagode $P(z)/z^n$ is analytic on $|z|/geq 1$, use the maximum modulus theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  $|z| \le M+1$,  $ |P(z)| \le M(M+1)^n $

Clearly, for $|z|=M+1$ , $|z^n|= (M+1)^n$

Now,  let  $Q(z) = P(z) - z^n = a_1z^{n-1} + a_2z^{n-2} + ...a_n$

Clearly, for $|z| \le1$,  $|Q(z)| - |z^n| \le |Q(z) +z^n| = |P(z)| \le  M$

$\implies |Q(z)| \le M+1 $,  for $|z| \le 1$

Using the first part, you can show,  $ |Q(z)| < (M+1)^n$ for $|z|<M+1$

So, on the boundary of  circle  $|z| = M+1$ , $Q(z) < |z^n|$

So, in the interior of circle,  $z^n$ and $z^n + Q(z) = P(z)$  will have same no. of zeroes.